# Find an inverse matrix, regarding a parameter as real

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, assumptions, inverse

I have the matrix

```
{{3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 3, -1}, 
{-(3/b), -(3/b^2) - 2/b, -(3/b^3) - 2/b^2 - 1/b}, 
{-(3/b), -(3/b^2) - 1/b, -(3/b^3) - 1/b^2 - 2/b}, 
{-(2/b), -(2/b^2) - 3/b, -(2/b^3) - 3/b^2 + 1/b}}
```

and I want to compute its inverse (or pseudoinverse).

The problem is that *Mathematica* solves this regarding `b` as a complex number.
How do I change this to set `b` as real? I tried `Assuming` but that didn't work. Maybe I am writing it wrong. Any ideas? It should be fairly simple, but I am not really good at `Mathematica` and I couldn't find a solution elsewhere.
I would be greatful for a general answer, not one specifically for this example;
e.g., `Pseudoinverse[a] /. Reals[b] -> ...` (this didn't work).

Thanks

Comment: Try `ComplexExpand[PseudoInverse[mat]]`.

Answer (score 8):

Usually simplifying the result with appropriate assumptions gives desired result:

```
m={{3, 2, 1},
 {3, 1, 2},
 {2, 3, -1},
 {-(3/b), -(3/b^2) - 2/b, -(3/b^3) - 2/b^2 - 1/b},
 {-(3/b), -(3/b^2) - 1/b, -(3/b^3) - 1/b^2 - 2/b},
 {-(2/b), -(2/b^2) - 3/b, -(2/b^3) - 3/b^2 + 1/b}};

Simplify[PseudoInverse[m], b \[Element] Reals]
```

Comment: Yes thats true,it works just fine, thank you very much you have been very helpful!